# How to make a variable light dimmer circuit without potentiometer?

Tags: capacitive, dimmer

I was looking at the Wemo dimmer and thought to make one at home myself because the price of it is very high if I buy (including import duty). I searched for the knowledge which helps me create a capacitive touch slider switch and I found this video:

1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_r_8z0pAQ-o

I have also watched this video:

2] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqg_Ze_OiiY&t=723s

and this one:

3] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mWR9Q_pTagw

which shows how can I create a capacitive touch switch using anything or Arduino Nano. I am thinking to use the ATMEGA328 microcontroller to create this capacitive touch circuit and will insert the code of the first video in the ATMEGA328 to run the capacitive slider touch switch.

My main problem is that I am not able to find a light dimmer circuit without the potentiometer. I need some guidance and help regarding how can I create one without a potentiometer and how can I join this dimmer circuit with the capacitive slider switch.

I am still researching this.

Comment: Note: Be careful with mains power. I won't say that you *can't*, but if I had this decision, I wouldn't build my own light dimmer. If the dimmer was too expensive I would choose to not have a dimmer. Maybe I would make a dimmer for a low voltage LED light. It's your choice, though.

Comment: @user253751 Thank you so much for your concern but if I don't make one now I wouldn't be able to learn to implement bigger things. As you said I am first going to test it on a 5V LED then I will try to implement it on Bulbs, lamps, etc. But first I need to find a perfect dimmer circuit without a potentiometer.

Comment: The light dimmer circuit works by turning the light on at a certain time within the mains frequency cycle, right? Why not use the microcontroller to tell it when to turn on? (ignoring, for now, the safety problems with having a microcontroller connected to a touch switch and the mains power - there are ways to solve those problem, like opto-isolation)

Comment: @user253751 a good concern, but the cure is to make the lights low voltage.  In the LED age this is easy.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica yeah you are right I have tried dimming 5V LEDs and it works great but I want to dim house lights like LED Bulbs, Lamps, etc.

Comment: Totally different.  "House lights like LED bulbs" are actually complex products with onboard electronics. They do not dim like 5V LEDs,  Their internal electronics will actively fight your attempts to dim it like a 5V LED. Mains voltage is not simply low voltage less low, it's a completely different animal. **It's easier to teach a violinist to play the bongoes than the other way 'round**, so I suggest converting the lighting to low voltage so you have maximum flexibility to apply known techniques.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Many household LED bulbs are designed to be dimmable - AFAIK, the internal electronics will try to estimate the dimmer setting and dim their own LEDs accordingly.

Comment: @user253751 correct, they analyze the triac waveshape to figure out what it's *trying* to do, then command that level of dimming via PWM or current control.  So the LED doesn't even need to shimmer at 120Hz like an incandescent does at dim levels! AC+dimming is a black art.

Comment: @user253751 Belated Merry Christmas and now can now What method or circuit I can use without potentiometer to act as a dimmer.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Belated Merry Christmas, now can you suggest a circuit used for dimming the AC Lamp, Bulbs, LED Bulbs without a potentiometer. So that I can also control the circuit through the Mobile Application.

Comment: @Lucifer Have you done any research? Do you understand how the potentiometer-based dimmers work?

Comment: @user253751 Yeah, I have done some research and what I think potentiometer(variable resistance) adjusts or controls the voltage supply and this voltage controls the Triac and Triac On and off the Fraction of AC wave to work as a dimmer. So the work of potentiometer is to control the voltage and I want to know how can I vary that without potentiometer so I can create one.

Comment: @Lucifer So the potentiometer is used to adjust one part of the circuit that generates an on/off signal?

Comment: @user253751 Sorry for the delay, I think yes, as I searched and all I got this info.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this several times, for testing etc I use 24VAC so I do not get hurt with the voltage and I get a reasonable close approximation to how it will operate. My last project was with a push button. Push it is on, push again it is off, push  on and hold it it will slowly get brighter then dimmer, with predefined limits at both ends. I used an Arduino for the controller. There is a lot of code posted that will perform this function. The main point is to do your testing with a lower voltage, I selected 24VAC as I had a transformer and bulbs. This also allows me to use a scope and other test equipment without too much concern about the ground connection and blowing things up.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question as I myself was searching for an answer like this a long time ago.

One possible way is to have:

1. Zero crossing circuit - I prefer this one:
   https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/zero-crossing-detector-using-4n35-optocoupler
2. Triac driver optocoupler **without** zero-crossing detection. MOC3021M is an example of one
3. Other stuff like triac itself with correct snubbing, power supplies, etc

However, It should be noted, though this project is pretty simple and straightforward - it involves mains **AND** touch sensor at same time. While it is easy to isolate everything with only two optocouplers, It is also true for an opposite. If there is not enough precaution in mains isolation - a strong shock would be the least awful outcome.  I would not recommend doing it unless you know what are you doing for sure.

Just buy one - it will be an easier, safer option. And no one will die. Probably

Comment: I am just going to create a PoC and I know what I am doing and I will do it with great care. I have created a simple Wi-Fi controlled switch using ESP12, Hilink 230V AC-3V DC and a DC 3V relay(before this a solid-state relay 3V) and created a webserver inside esp12 to turn on and off the device. Therefore just I need to add these above functionalities in it.

So according to the second option, I should create a dimmer circuit using the MOC3021M and Your Third option went right over my head.